# Do processor caches invalidated when process is switched?

Tags: caching, process, operating-system, cpu, virtual-address-space

Do processor caches work with virtual or physical address space? Probably it can work with both, depending on processor looks into cache after or before translating address. So when it uses virtual addresses, after process switch all addresses became invalid. Does processor invalidate caches when process is switched? In this case cache seems useless, so there must be another  solution I think. (does it keep process ID with addresses?)

Thanks.

Comment: From the perspective of `Intel` processors what is close to process switch is the moment when OS changes the descriptor tables (see `LGDT` instruction). Furthermore there is not much that OS can do about caching as this is hidden inside the processor itself. See `cache line` in [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf). What kind of problem are you solving?